# Using Async for a Network activity

Tags: android, asynchronous, networking, android-asynctask

I understand that network tasks should be done in an Async thread, and I think my code is inside one, but I still get the error

.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

which confuses me, since pretty much everything is inside an Async task:

```
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new GetRssFeedTask().execute();
    }
```

The rest of the code is inside the Async task:

```
  private class GetRssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private String getRssFeed() throws IOException {
            InputStream in = null;
            String rssFeed = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://stuffilikenet.wordpress.com/feed/main.xml");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                in = conn.getInputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
                rssFeed = new String(response, "UTF-8");
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            }
            return rssFeed;
        }      

  ...rest of code (seriously)...
  }
```

Where should I look for my error?

Comment: Post your `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: your code should be in the doInBackground() not just some method you create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

network tasks should be done in an doInBackground() .

> doInBackground() callback method runs in a pool of background
>   threads. To update your UI, you should implement onPostExecute(),
>   which delivers the result from doInBackground() and runs in the UI
>   thread, so you can safely update your UI.

- perform initilization in onPreExecute() method
- perform background task in doInBackground() method
- update the UI in onPostExecute() method

  ```
  public class MyAyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      //Here you can show progress bar or something on the similar lines.
      //Since you are in a UI thread here.
      super.onPreExecute();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // Here you are in the worker thread and you are not allowed to access UI thread from here
      //Here you can perform network operations or any heavy operations you want.
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
      super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
      //After completing execution of given task , control will return here.
      //Hence if you want to populate UI elements with fetched data, do it here
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      // You can track you progress update here
  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to do define the network operations inside your `AsyncTask` class to run them on a background `Thread`.

You have to execute them inside `doInBackgrund()`.

You need to override `doInBackground()` inside your `AsyncTask` class and perform your network operations there.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // here
    return null;
}
```